# How to use subscribe in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to retrieve all the orders placed by a customer.
So, in my component I've written like below.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.customerId = this.getCustomer();
    this.orderHistoryItems = this.getOrders();
}

getCustomer(): string {
    this._accountService.getCustomer()
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.GeneralStatus.toString() === 'Success') {
                return response.Result.CustomerId;
            }
        });
    return "";
}

getOrders(): OrderHistory[] {

    this._trackOrdersService.getOrders(this.customerId)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.GeneralStatus.toString() === 'Success') {
                return response.Result;
            } 
        });
    return [];
}
```

**When I invoke this, for the first time I'm getting the customerId as `undefined`**. Control is not even entering in if condition in `subscribe` in above `getCustomer()` method.
If I reload the same page then I'm getting the customerId and orders as well. I've written respective http calls for `getCustomer` and `getOrders` like below.

```
getOrders(custId) {
    return this._http.get(`${this.apiUrl}GetOrders?CustomerID=${custId}`, { headers: this.headers })
        .retry(2)
        .map(function (res) {
            return res.json();
        });
}

getCustomer(): Observable<ApiResponse<Customer, string>> {
    return this._http.get('${this.apiUrl}LoggedInCustomer', { headers: this.headers })
        .retry(2)
        .map((response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Please help me if there is any mistake in above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to return the result in your `subscribe` call, which won't work, since you're in an inline function.

A way would be to return the `Observable` once again or to pass a callback like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomer((id) => {
        this.customerId = id;
    });

    this.getOrders((orderItems) => {
        this.orderHistoryItems = orderItems;
    });
}

getCustomer(callback: (id) => void) {
    this._accountService.getCustomer()
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.GeneralStatus.toString() === 'Success') {
                callback(response.Result.CustomerId);
            }
        });
}

getOrders(callback: (orderItmes: OrderHistory[]) => void) {

    this._trackOrdersService.getOrders(this.customerId)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.GeneralStatus.toString() === 'Success') {
                callback(response.Result);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'll try this for returning values from subscribe. Can you also please tell me why for the first timeI'm getting customerId as ""(i.e. control is not coming upto if condition. So, with enpty customerId it is trying to fetch orders which is wrong. After getOrders call completes it execution, now control is going to If condition id getCustomer()  and getting customerId.

Comment: Because that's not how Observables work - with my aproach there shouldn't be any problems anymore